# How to set typeahead default/initial value for Angular 2 ng-bootstrap?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm using template for result example from ng-bootstrap.github.io.

This works perfectly fine. I use it for user to input city in a form.

Problem is with editing user details. I'm not sure how to populate previously saved city for that user. This is what I have in HTML:

```
<template #rt let-r="result" let-t="term">
    {{ r.name}}
</template>
<input (blur)="lostFocus($event)" class="form-control" formControlName="city_obj" type="text" [(ngModel)]="typeaheadModel" [ngbTypeahead]="search" [resultTemplate]="rt" [inputFormatter]="formatter" (selectItem) = "selectItem($event)">
```

This is from component:

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
text$
.debounceTime(200)
.map(term => term === '' ? []
    : this.cities.filter(v => new RegExp(term, 'gi').test(v.name)).slice(0, 10));
formatter = (x: {name: string}) => x.name;
```

I use model driven forms.

In database, I save only city id for the user, since cities are in separate table.

So, in the form builder I have city_id field and city_obj.

API will only save city_id and disregard city_obj.

I use selectItem event to set the city_id field in component.

So, how can I set previously saved city to input and keep typeahead functionality?

Comment: It seems you are describing Reactive forms.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Discovered it myself.

I just had to set the same object to the form control, but after debounceTime.

EDIT: Since this was long time ago, I don't know if this is right approach. And since there is a lot of interest in this, I found the project where I used this. Here's what I did at the time to set the typeahead value and it worked fine:

```
this.form.controls['city_obj'].setValue({id:this.formData.city.id, name:this.formData.city.name});
```

Comment: Can you update the source code after solution please? @igor

Comment: Same here. Can you please update the source code? I am having the same issue in "edit" mode. Not sure how to set the typeahead with an existing value. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

set data in the constructor or ngOnInit method for ngmodel like this.

```js
constructor(){
   this.typeaheadModel = {
     name : "test name"
   }
}
```